# Image urls not loading

Tags: reactjs

ImageGrid() comp is displaying images.
image urls are https urls.

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";


function ImageGrid(props) {
  const imageRef = useRef();

  const handleImageChange = () => {
    const imgRef = imageRef.current.value;
    console.log("img ref: ", imgRef); // 2 - undefined
  };

  return (
    <div className="gallery" ref={imageRef}>
      <div className="images">
        {props.imageList.map((obj) => { // 1 - 500 status code
          return (
            <img
              src={obj.imageURL}
              onLoad={handleImageChange}
              onError={handleImageChange}
              alt=""
              key={obj.imageURL}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default ImageGrid;
```

1. some images are not loading and giving 500 internal error, even though image urls are working fine. how to make sure to load images?
2. also, 'imgRef' is 'undefined' in 'handleImageChange'. why div ref is failing?

[image: 500 status code for image urls]

I am able to navigate to all urls successfully. it's just that few images are taking time to load. how to handle it?

Comment: const imgRef = imageRef.current；A div dom should not have value prop.

Comment: @gwl002 yes, i tried without 'value', it worked. thanks.

Comment: This error is not related to react, it's rather a server issue, check if you can navigate to the urls that you provide to the image elements. It's everything ok with your component code.

Comment: @micnic I am able to navigate to all urls successfully. it's just that few images are taking time to load.